# Base64 clipping images

Tags: javascript, php, image-processing, base64

The following code is taking a base64 string provided by a plugin called cropit and converting it to an image.

```
list($type, $base64) = explode(';', $base64);
list(, $base64)      = explode(',', $base64);
$base64 = str_replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "", $base64);
$base64 = base64_decode($base64);

file_put_contents($directory, $base64);
```

I'll also provide my javascript that is sending the base64 to the php function through the use of an input. I know that the issue is being caused by PHP because when I send `imageData` to a new window the image will show up perfectly with no issues.

```
$('.export_upload').click(function() {
    $("#upload_form_identifier").val("upload_form");

    var imageData = $('.image-editor-upload').cropit('export', {
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        quality: 0.3,
        originalSize: true
    });

    //Set value of hidden input to base64
    $("#hidden_base64_upload").val(imageData);

    //Pause form submission until input is populated
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.upload_form.submit();
    }, 1000);
});
```

The issue I'm having is that if I input an image it will clip it in a random spot. Could PHP be running out of memory? I'm not very experience with base64 so I really don't have any idea what could be causing this. Any help would  be great.

Original Image:
[image: Original Image]

After PHP processes base64:
[image: After PHP processes base64]

Comment: Divide and conquer, check your JS and make sure you are actually passing the expected base64 string to the server.

Comment: @angelcool.net This was my first thought but I double and tripled checked. The base64 that my Javascript is exporting is the exact same as what PHP sees. When I view the actual base64 string from javascript in my browser the image displays with no issues.

Comment: @angelcool.net Already tried this with no luck.

Comment: If this is pulled from a database by any chance, then you'll need to modify your colum type as MEDIUMBLOB, or LONGBLOB as opposed to just BLOB. I've answered a question similar to this before, where that's what the problem was. Reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html @Coilerz

Comment: If it's a PHP memory limit issue, consult http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php and increase the memory as well as the execution time to 0. http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's not being pulled from a database.

Comment: @angelcool.net I've tried other images and unless the image size is below 500kb it will give this issue. Sometimes I'm able to upload a 1.2mb image or larger and it will work but it's really just hit or miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this isn't the best solution it works for me and will probably suit your needs. The issue I've found is with `originalSize: true` having this will export the cropped part of the image without any compression resulting in a very large base64. The way I solve it is by setting `originalSize` to false and then resizing the preview to a size that I will use. The code below should work.

```
$('.export_upload').click(function() {
            $("#upload_form_identifier").val("upload_form");

            $('.image-editor-upload').cropit('previewSize', {width:1024, height:1024});

            var imageData = $('.image-editor-upload').cropit('export', {
                type: 'image/jpeg',
                quality: .75,
                originalSize: false
            });



            //Set value of hidden input to base64
            $("#hidden_base64_upload").val(imageData);

            //Pause form submission until input is populated
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                window.open(imageData);
                document.upload_form.submit();
            }, 1000);
        });
```

The key is `$('.image-editor-upload').cropit('previewSize', {width:1024, height:1024});`. This resizes the image before sending it to the php function. The only real issue with this is that if the user modifies the javascript they will be able to change the output size of the image but this shouldn't be an issue if you verify the upload with php to ensure the Width and height match what you put inside of the brackets.

I came up with a basic verification function today. It will return true or false based on if the dimensions of the image are correct or not. You can apply this to your initial form where the image is getting set and check if it matches or not and throw errors accordingly.

```
/**
 * Checks the dimensions of the provided image
 * @param  string $base64_image Base64 string of the image
 * @param  string $width Desired width of the image
 * @param  string $height Desired height of the image
 * @return bool True if dimensions match, false if dimensions do not match
 */
public function checkImageDimensions ($base64_image, $width, $height) {
    list($type, $base64_image) = explode(';', $base64_image);
    list(, $base64_image)      = explode(',', $base64_image);
    $base64_image = base64_decode($base64_image);

    $dimensions = getimagesizefromstring($base64_image);

    if ($dimensions[0] == $width && $dimensions[1] == $height) {
        return true;
    } else if ($dimensions[0] !== $width && $dimensions[1] !== $height) {
        return false;
    }
}
```